# Use a hashtable or array as bitmap when checking for characters

Tags: c, arrays, hashtable, lookup

Say I want to have some kind of a bitmap to know the number of times a particular char appears in a string.

So, for example, if I read the string "abracadabra", I would have a data structure that would look something like this:

```
a -> 5
b -> 2
r -> 2
c -> 1
d -> 1
```

I have read a book ([Programming INterviews Exposed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047012167X)) that says the following:

Hashtables have a higher lookup overhead than arrays. 
An array would need an element for every possible character. 
A hashtable would need to store just the characters that actually appear in the string.
Therefore:

Arrays are a better choice for long strings with a limited set of possible characters and hash tables are more efficient for shorter strings or when there are many possible character values.

I don't understand why:

-> Hashtables have a higher lookup overhead than arrays? Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

An array is an extremely simple data structure. In memory, it is a simple contiguous block. Say each item in the array is four bytes, and the array has room for 100 elements. Then the array is simply 400 contiguous bytes in memory, and your variable assigned to the array is a pointer to the first element. Say this is at location 10000 in memory.

When you access element #3 of the array, like this:

```
myarray[3] = 17;
```

...what happens is very simple: 3 multiplied by the element size (4 bytes) is added to the base pointer. In this example it's 10000 + 3 * 4 = 10012. Then you simply write to the 4 bytes located at address 10012. Trivially simple math.

A hashtable is not an elementary data structure. It could be implemented in various ways, but a simple one might be an array of 256 lists. Then when you access the hashtable, first you have to calculate the hash of your key, then look up the right list in the array, and finally walk along the list to find the right element. This is a *much* more complicated process.

A simple array is always going to be faster than a hashtable. What the text you cite is getting at is that if the data is very *sparse*... you might need a very large array to do this simple calculation. In that case you could use a lot less memory space to hold the hash table.

Consider if your characters were Unicode -- two bytes each. That's 65536 possible characters. And say you're only talking about strings with 256 or fewer characters. To count those characters with an array, you would need to make an array with 64K elements, one byte each... taking 64K of memory. The hashtable on the other hand, implemented like I mentioned above, might take only 4*64 bytes for the array of list pointers, and then 5-8 bytes per list element. So if you were processing a 256-character string with say 64 unique Unicode characters used, it would take up a total of at most 768 bytes. Under these conditions, the hashtable would be using much less memory. But it's always going to be slower.

Finally, in the simple case you show, you're probably just talking about the Latin alphabet, so if you force lowercase, you could have an array with just 26 elements, and make them as large as you want so you could count as many characters as you'll need. Even if it's 4 billion, you would need just 26 * 4 = 104 character array. So that's definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Wonderful explaination. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Hashtables have a higher lookup overhead than arrays? Why is that?

When accessing an array for a charcter counting it is a direct access:
counter[c]++;

While a hastable is a (complex) data structure, where first a hash function must be calculated, then a second function to reduce the hascode to hash table position.
If the table position already is used, additional action has to be done.

I personally think, that as long as your characters are in Asci Range (0-255) the array approach is always faster, and more suited. If it comes to uni code character (which in java is the default in Strings, then the hashtable is more appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

> Hashtables have a higher lookup overhead than arrays? Why is that?

Because they have to <s>search for the key</s> calculate the hash from the key.

In contrast, arrays have `O(1)` lookup time. For accessing a value in an array, typically calculating the offset and returning the element at that offset is enough, this works in constant time.

Comment: OP is comparing Array to Hashtable. Both have O(1).

Comment: Assuming we are actually using the hashtable to reduce the amount of storage needed [not sure that's necessary for an array of at most 256?], then you'd have to look through a linked list [or similar] of items for each hash-bucket.

Comment: @ezneme Don't forget that O(1) or any O() does NOT show the constant overhead! O(1) = c. O(1); the pre-factor c for arrays is much lower than for a hastable, so c1*O(1) is not neccessarily c2* O(1): I dont kwow why nearly evrybody fogets this when using the Big O notation.

Comment: Actually the joke of the hashtable is that you DON'T sort the contents. You use the hashfunction to determine the position in the table. (In addition you have a collision resolution scheme). So the slowdown comes from calculating the hashvalue and the conflicht resultion rather than from a search"

Comment: @junix In one type. But there are other data structures that are referred to as "hash tables" yet they don't calculate hashes, but compare keys. Have you heard of `std::map`? (Also, no need to downvote an answer jut because you don't like it. Upvote others that you find better.)

Comment: @H2CO3 According to computer science literature and even wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) a hash table/hash map is a data structure that calculates the position of an entry by applying a (hash-)function to the key and does a proper conflict resolution. Starting from that point, your answer (including the guess for the cause of the higher latency)  is incorrect and therefore not useful. And that's why I downvoted it, not because I "don't like it". I even upvoted two good explainations for this question although I found one better than the other. But at least both are correct.

Comment: @H2CO3 did you exchanged tree map with hashmap?

Comment: @H2CO3 No need to scream, buddy. As you can see I removed the down vote as the facts are now correct. Unfortunately I have to admit, that I won't stop downvoting in general because that's what the system is for. And it's even more important if a guy with high reputation provides incorrect information in his answer. So calm down, have a cup of tea and enjoy the day.

Comment: @junix the problem was that the information was not incorrect.

Comment: @H2CO3 Really? Just another "i was correct" discussion? Could you please at least provide some information why you think the information was correct?